# CC-mode assignment indenting in Emacs

Tags: c++, emacs, indentation

I am writing a C++ program with Emacs CC-mode, When I write an expression that needs to wrap, how can I make the newline on the right side of the equal sign like this:

```
// Aligned
abc = longlonglong + longlonglong +
      longlonglong;

// The actual situation
abc = longlonglong + longlonglong +
    longlonglong;
```

With StackOverflow's hints, I tried several ways to customize the `statement-cont` variable, but only one method worked -- added the following code in `~/.emacs`:

```
(c-add-style "Stroustrup"
     '((c-basic-offset . 4)
       (c-offsets-alist
    (statement-cont . c-lineup-assignments))))
```

I found [google-c-style.el](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/google-c-style.el)'s settings as follows:

```
    (c-offsets-alist . ((arglist-intro google-c-lineup-expression-plus-4)
                    ...
                    (statement-cont
                     .
                     (,(when (fboundp 'c-no-indent-after-java-annotations)
                         'c-no-indent-after-java-annotations)
                      ,(when (fboundp 'c-lineup-assignments)
                         'c-lineup-assignments)
                      ++))
                    ...
                    (innamespace . 0))))
```

Who can tell me what this code means?

Because I only want to apply `c-lineup-assignments` to equations, I updated my settings reference to google-style code:

```
(c-add-style "Stroustrup"
     '((c-basic-offset . 4)
       (c-offsets-alist 
    (statement-cont . (when (looking-at "=")
                'c-lineup-assignments
                '+)))))
```

But when I run `cc-mode` the Emacs says *Invalid indentation setting for symbol statement-cont: ....*, so if I want only to apply the `c-lineup-assignments` to equations, how can I change this code ?

Comment: You'll be happy to discover the wonders of Emacs and Lisp language ...
May the force be with you

Comment: You want this to only apply to equations? Or just adjust your newline indent in general?

Comment: Have you considered Emacs + Clang-Format: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html#emacs-integration ? IMHO this is the best tool for C++ code formatting

Comment: I just only apply to equations.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `c-lineup-assignments` from `cc-align`. With your cursor on the continuation line, when you can type <kbd>C-c C-o</kbd> (or `c-set-offset` in case that key is modified) it should autofill with `c-statement-cont`. Hit return and set its value to `c-lineup-assignments`.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried several ways to update the `statement-cont` parameter, only use `c-add-style` worked.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific why that doesn't work for you. Start emacs with `emacs -Q` and try.  You should be able to use `c-set-offset` either in the C buffer or in your `c-mode-hook`, eg. `(add-hook 'c-mode-hook #'(lambda () (c-set-offset 'statement-cont 'c-lineup-assignments)))`. You can evaluate in your scratch buffer and reload the C buffer.

Comment: I have tried three ways: use <kbd>C-cC-o</kbd> to customize the `statement-cont`, use the `c-mode-hook` like you say, and use `c-add-style`(my Emacs version is 25.1.1), only the last method worked. so I have updated my question, care more about how to apply the `c-lineup-assignments` only to equations, anyway, thanks for your help!